# How to set and update ICC card PIN with APDU command

Tags: authentication, smartcard, apdu, icc, emv

I have a contact smartcard.(I dont know about what kind of applet installed on it. But I can authenticate, read, update and verify pin with standart APDU commands.) And I want to do some changes on PIN.
So, my question is:

- If card has PIN, then update the PIN with new value. If card dont have any PIN, then set PIN.

Standart update command is not working on PIN file. I am getting 6982 response message from ICC card. So, what is the approach to success above situation. 
I searched on internet about it, But I didnt find any useful Docs&Articles.

Comment: ISO 7816-4 has the dedicated command *Change Reference Data*. But without any documentation concerning your specific card and whats on it, (so which operations are allowed after which authentication involving which PIN/key), chances for substantial progress are small.

Comment: Actually, my purpose was learning steps for any kind of card. Mostly they are same. If we consider any banking credit card, what is the approach to change PIN? I am authenticating on the card. after that I am sending 00 24 00 10 10 OLD_PIN + NEW_PIN, then I am getting 6982 error. So... Are there any tip.

Comment: For a banking card check EMV specification. And I don't agree with *mostly they are the same*; cards are still very different to each other and only detailed specifications as EMV achieve similarity. You give 10 as  PIN id - no idea, whether this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found solution, and I am putting the answer here.

Firstly, we need to select PIN FILE. For this

- Select MF(Master File)
- Select DF(Dedicated file)
- Select PIN EF (Elementry file)

> Select App Master File : **00 A4 00 00 02 XX XX**
>
> Select App Dedicated File : **00 A4 00 00 02 XX XX**
>
> Select App Pin File : **00 A4 00 00 02 XX XX**
>
> Change Pin coommand: **00 24 [TM] [KN] [LN] XX XX .. ..**
>
> TM: Transfer Mode (Clear Transfer) : **00** KN: Key Number: 10 LN:
>   Total Pin Length(Every time 16 bytes): **10**
>
> For example (Old pin is “**1234**” and we want to change pin to
>   “**5678**”:
>
> Change Pin : **00 24 00 10 10 31 32 33 34 FF FF FF FF 35 36 37 38 FF
>   FF FF FF** (FF: padding value)

Answer (score 0):

Error 6982 stands for "Security condition not satisfied".

PINs are never transmitted plain as you have mentioned in your packet. They are always encrypted for the software involved between a User and the ICC can sneak peak the packet. A public key has to be obtained using GET_CHALLENGE command and used for enciphering of the PIN.

According EMV spec, the APDU for PIN change is

```
CLA = 8C or 84;
INS = 24
P1 = 00
P2 = 01/ 02
Lc = Number of data bytes
Data = Enciphered PIN data component, if present, and MAC data component;
```

- CLA and Data are to be coded according to the secure messaging specified in EMV Book 2
- P2 = 01 => PIN Data Generated Using the Current PIN
- P2 = 02 => PIN Data Generated Without Using the Current PIN
- new PIN is encapsulated in the Data field